# How do I make a post request to an HTTP server from inside an office js excel add-in?

Tags: office-js

It seems to me that office js excel add-ins block connection to a REST API HTTP server. Can someone help me get around this?

Answer (score 0):

See [Addressing same-origin policy limitations in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/addressing-same-origin-policy-limitations).